# loop through range to populate coordinates based upon value in range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am working with an excel spreadsheet for camera calibration.  In this spreadsheet, there is an option to use 14 out of 78 targets available.  I have begun to write code which loops through the range of targets used, based upon the value in each cell it will populate the adjacent cells with x, y and z coordinate values.  Initially only made for loop to go through range and manually wrote 78 if statements to serve each target.  Well, I am sure there is a better way to do this by implementing another for loop.  what I have keeps going into an endless loop.

**My code attempt**

```
Sub macro()

Dim rng As range, cell As range

Set rng = range("d2:d15")

' Target 1
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To 78
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = j Then
            Cells(i, 5) = Cells(26 + j, 2)
            Cells(i, 6) = Cells(26 + j, 3)
            Cells(i, 7) = Cells(26 + j, 4)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: if  you share your data , we can offer a better solution. how do you keep the values of 78 targets ? is it inside an array ? are they kept in another worksheet ? why are you setting `rng` but never using it later ?

Comment: its not endless, i is just running for 1048576, if you are on Excel 2007+, because of Rows.Count.

Comment: The target coordinates are kept inside the same sheet.  x, y, and z beginning at b27, c 27, and d 27.  Here is an  example copied from the spread sheet.   
Target X Y Z 
1 0.994076386 2.871819521 7.414613305 
2 0.001286094 2.329521288 7.405560172 
3 0.001367373 0.816107316 7.485133244 
4 0.993239568 2.88548805 6.234767026 
5 0.001790363 2.355691937 6.328347983 
6 0.580815367 2.386308878 4.521358343

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be refactoredas follows

```
Sub macro()
    Dim rng As range, cell As range

    Set rng = range("d2:d15")
    For Each cell in rng
        If cell>=1 And cell <=78 Then cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,3).Value = Cells(26 + j, 2).Resize(,3).Value
    Next
End Sub
```